# Many data to one record MYSQL

Tags: mysql, record

I have a table named medOrder. In this table I have orders. One order has many wishes. I tried to write a query that shows one record and all the names of the wishes but I don't think the query is as good as it  could be.

```
SELECT m.ordcode as koden, w.wish, r.meaName as rnamn, r.meaImg as bild, 
        r.meaPrice as pris, k.catName as cname from cats k, meals r, wishes w,
        meaOrder m
    join orders c on c.ordNR='7265'
    WHERE m.ordNR=c.ordNR AND m.meaID=r.meaID AND m.wishesID=w.id
        AND r.catID=k.catID
    ORDER BY m.ordcode DESC;
```

[image: data schema]

Comment: You should update the question with details about your schema, and what it's not working with your current query.

Comment: My current query works fine, but not like i want it. In meaOrder i have one order in many rows, just because one order have many wishes, so i want a query that shows order in one row and shows all wishes who connected to the order. http://i.imgur.com/irTua.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT koden, GROUP_CONCAT(wish) wish, rnamn, bild, pris, cname 
FROM
(
SELECT m.ordcode as koden, w.wish, r.meaName as rnamn, r.meaImg as bild, 
        r.meaPrice as pris, k.catName as cname from cats k, meals r, wishes w,
        meaOrder m
    join orders c on c.ordNR='7265'
    WHERE m.ordNR=c.ordNR AND m.meaID=r.meaID AND m.wishesID=w.id
        AND r.catID=k.catID
) T
GROUP BY koden, rnamn, bild, pris, cname
ORDER BY koden DESC
```

This query does `GROUP BY` on all the repeating columns but concatenate values for the non-repeating column of `wish`.

Comment: Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: i tried to mark every single order by "ordcode" (koden) and then tried to do GROUP BY koden, but i did´nt went well, it shows only one row.

Comment: This query groups by koden (or ordcode), so it would generate different rows for different ordcode. Did you try the modified query? I added alias `T`.